# test for level stationarity in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series

Does anyone know how to test level stationarity of a time series in Matlab as in [R](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=tseries%3akpss.test)? [KPSS test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/econ/kpsstest.html) can only test trend stationarity in Matlab.

I just found there is a 'trend' parameter for kpsstest in Matlab. Does kpsstest test level stationarity by setting 'trend' to be false ?

Answer (score 1):

You could test for autocorrelation. If a plot of autocorr vs. tau(offset), a correlogram, diminishes to zero you have stationarity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlogram

There is a matlab correlogram plotter on the file exchange:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30540-autocorrelation-function-acf

Also, the rate of decay of the correlogram corresponds to the decay in self-similarity. If adjacent points in a time series are truly random, the ACF decays to zero instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Try `adftest` from Econometrics Toolbox.

Comment: Thanks. But adftest does not include level stationarity neither.